# How do I return a different view for a different orientation?

Tags: responsive-design, swiftui

I have a view which is a `VStack` of two other views, and that is all it is.

This works great in portrait orientation (or tall/skinny macOS windows), but it is squished, awkward, and some parts aren't usable in landscape (or wide/short macOS windows).

**How do I make this view return a `VStack` when it's portrait/tall/skinny, but a `HStack` when it's landscape/wide/short?**

I tried many things, but all resulted in compilers errors. Since SwiftUI is so new, I couldn't find anything on the web about this.

Comment: Just be aware that the accepted answer won't work on an iPad. All iPads always yield a regular size class in all orientations. The only time they have a compact size is when in split screen.

Comment: Thank you, @dfd. Please, if you have a better answer, do post it here.

Comment: #1. I most certainly do not! I've always felt this to be a weakness of using size classes. My best `UIKit` answer - one I have always used because my image editing app need to emphasize the "image" is to place the editing controls below the image in portrait and to the right of the image in landscape. And I have a set of extensions to `UIView` snd `UIViewController` that depend on their lifecycles and measure the height/width of the screen, something I won't do with the iPad-only `SwiftuUI` app I'm working on.

Comment: #2. I *really* don't like how this app looks on my iPad mini in portrait, but I've accepted that that's the price one pays for working on the bleeding edge. Just like how you need to work with a `UIImage` (or `CIImage with their `extent` property) to get how many points - not pixels - in an image size, this is something I'm hoping Apple will correct someday. I'm just making sure *you* know that this "gap" with using size classes exist.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I solved this using a GeometryReader and comparing the width and height. If width > height, the device is in landscape otherwise in portrait mode:

```
struct MyView: View {
    var body: some View {
        return GeometryReader { proxy in
            if proxy.size.width < proxy.size.height {
                VStack {
                    ...
                }
            } else {
                HStack {
                    ...
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I made this my accepted answer because, after much testing, this was also the solution I used

Answer (score 3):

You can react to the environment. For example, if you would like to react to the horizontalSizeClass (regular vs compact):

```swift
struct MyView: View {
    @Environment(\.horizontalSizeClass) var horizontalSizeClass: UserInterfaceSizeClass

    var body: some View {
        Group {

            if horizontalSizeClass == .regular {
                HStack {
                    Text("A")
                    Text("B")
                }
            } else { // compact
                VStack {
                    Text("A")
                    Text("B")
                }

            }
        }.border(Color.red)
    }
}
```

Comment: This just gives the error "Closure containing control flow statement cannot be used with function builder 'ViewBuilder'"

Comment: What you can write in a SwiftUI View body is very restricted by the ViewBuilder. You cannot use any control-flow statements. In fact, when you use "if", you're not using a full swift if. Unfortunately, the compiler is not always too clear about it. For other cases, it is. For example, if you try to put the following: `if let x = 3, horizontalSizeClass == .regular`, the compiler will be more clear: ***Closure containing control flow statement cannot be used with function builder 'ViewBuilder'***

Comment: With switch, it is more of the same. Bottom line, you cannot use it :-(

Comment: I see you deleted your previous comment and replaced it. When you say it doesn't work. You refer to my posted answer?

Comment: I see... I'm sorry about the comment editing/deleting confusion. I was getting a lot of oddness with the compiler and didn't quite know what to say. This whole SwiftUI thing needs a lot of maturation; it's just full of exceptions and oddness not seen anywhere else in the language. Thank you for helping!

Comment: Your answer ended up being exactly what I needed 

Comment: Great. Cheers!!